# Host Angular App in virtual directory return index for all paths

Tags: angular, nginx

I am completely lost here, I am trying to host an angular app in a path, and i cannot get it to work.

I tried different hosting methods, apache, iis, nginx, where i am adding the setting `"baseHref": "/app/"`  in `angular.json`, but i always just get the `index.html` for for whatever file i request, even assets.

This is my nginx approach (`default.conf`)

```
    location /app/ {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html =404;
    }
```

I tried hosting in `/usr/share/nginx/html/app`, too, but as expected, this changes nothing. hosting from `location /` works just fine though.

Edit: I dismissed the idea of files never hitting the backend because of an angular misconfiguration. At this point it really looks like a backend misconfig. Maybe I start searching for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was, that due to an unfortunate chaining of reverse proxies sometimes the path was at root sometimes it was at /app/, so the solution was to add a url rewrite module at several places to make sure the /app/ part was never there except for the first reverse proxy. Probably would have worked other way round to.